# Passing a HTML tag in vue js

Tags: vue.js

I have a component which has a `<p>` tag inside, but would like it to be a `<h1>` tag sometimes, how to pass the prop ?

```
<template>
 <p>Hello world</p>
</template>
```

Answer (score 1):

Pass it as prop then use [`component`](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/built-in-components.html#component) to render it :

```
<template>
 <component :is="tag">Hello world</component >
</template>

<script>
export default{
  name:'MyComponent',
  props:['tag']
}
</script
```

then use the component like `<MyComponent tag="h1" />`

You could make `MyComponent` more dynamic  accepting any content by using slots :

```
<template>
 <component :is="tag">{{msg}}</component >
</template>

<script>
export default{
  name:'MyComponent',
  props:['tag','msg']
}
</script
```

then use it like `<MyComponent tag="h1" >hello world</MyComponent>`

Comment: hi thank you for your answer ! this wasnt what i was looking for, I would like sometimes to display a p tag instead of a h1 tag with the same text content, i guess we need to do a if else condition

Comment: You could do `<MyComponent tag="p" />`

Answer (score 0):

Would recommend using slot for that component, which will be something like this

```
<template>
  <slot name="content"></slot>
</template>
```

When you use your component you can just do this

```
<Component>
  <template #content>
    Your content here, whatever you like
  <template/>
<Component/>
```

Comment: hi thank you for your answer, i think your answer refers to a prop not displaying a html tag !

Comment: @fancy56 No my answer is a proper way to change component content without making a mess